# Sending input from a HTML website to an Android application

Tags: android, html

So i'm working on a summer project to create my first android app.  Here's the basic idea:  It's a workout app where a user goes to a website and submit's a text form of a workout.  This app will then parse the text file format it onto an android app they can take to the gym.

So far I just have some classes written in java to hold the workouts and an html website.  How would I go about sending the text from the website to the app?  If you could point me in the right direction or give me some examples of how this is done that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the GREAT Google Cloud Messaging System as the backbone for your applications.

> Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) is a free service that enables developers
>   to send downstream messages (from servers to GCM-enabled client apps),
>   and upstream messages (from the GCM-enabled client apps to servers).
>   This could be a lightweight message telling the client app that there
>   is new data to be fetched from the server (for instance, a "new email"
>   notification informing the app that it is out of sync with the back
>   end), or it could be a message containing up to 4kb of payload data
>   (so apps like instant messaging can consume the message directly). The
>   GCM service handles all aspects of queueing of messages and delivery
>   to and from the target client app.

**Work flow of the GCM**
[image: GCM WORK FLOW]

[Check this example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Comment: If my answer helped you, you could mark it as the correct answer.